# Handling WebException properly

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am calling a webservice through WSDL generated proxy classes. In case of webexceptions how can we handle its cases to make sure we capture all information.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I believe this will always contains some information but it says in the article

> This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

Then it proceeds to give an example using it the code here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

```
 if(e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) {
        Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine("Status Description : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
    }
```

- > How to best handle this exception. My priorities are     1) capturing
  >   the exception information which i belive is `e.Status`? 2) HTTP codes/description         (like 500
  >   internal server error)
- > will the StatusCode / StatusDescription be populated only when `e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError` because another `e.status = WebExceptionStatus.TimeOut` will it not be a `599` http error code or `499` when `WebExceptionStatus.ConnectionClosed` ?
- > what does **MSDN** mean by supports the product infrastructure and  don't use this in code?
- > will i need to capture any other information in case of other error status when its not a protocol exception (just for trapping more info for debugging like in case of the code sample in **MSDN** for `ProtocolError`).